# How to remove app.js in Laravel but keep vue.js?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I want to remove `"public/app.js"` from my `Laravel` project, but when I do that my `vue.js` instance doesn't work.
Is there any way to remove `app.js` but keep calling `vue.js`?

Comment: Why do you want to remove app.js? Do you even know what that is?

Comment: Can you add more information on your issue & application setup?

Comment: @PatrickHollweck I am using custom theme, and when I call app.js a lot of functions don't work.
also when I don't call "app.js" in my project everything is going well but I want to use vue.js

Comment: @atymic I am using Laravel Framework 5.8.24, and I have my own themes and template, my problem is when I call "app.js" a lot of functions of my template don't work. and when I don't call it I don't see any problem but it doesn't call vue.js

Comment: Have you edited anything in your `app.js` or `bootstrap.js` file or does it still contain the same code that was installed with your app? For the most part, the `app.js` is just vue. It does set up some other librarys/packages as well but these can easily be taken out. It might be easier if you add some of the errors to your question.

Comment: @Rwd it does still contain the same code that was installed with my app. In console I have only this error:
`jQuery.Deferred exception: general.body.imagesLoaded is not a function TypeError: general.body.imagesLoaded is not a function`
and:
`Uncaught TypeError: general.body.imagesLoaded is not a function`.

some of functions which doesn't work when I call "app.js":
- images slider.
- navbar menu buttons.

Comment: Are you using laravel-mix to compile your files? Also, does the theme that you're using include jQuery?

Comment: @Rwd before I start working I run `npm run watch`, but my own files I just included them in (public/assets/) and I call them in my app.blade.php.
and yes the theme uses jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only wanting to include `vue` in your application you can either remove the code you don't want from `app.js` or pull in a standalone version of `vue`.

To just have vue in your `app.js` remove the `require('./bootstrap');` line from your `resources/js/app.js` file and then run `npm run dev` (or `npm run production`).

---

Otherwise, you can remove `app.js` entirely and use one of the methods outlined on [Vue's installation page](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html) e.g.:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

You may need to change the version number.

---

Comment: It works! thank you so much, the most important thing to remove the `require('./bootstrap');` and everything will go well.